# prolog solve(X)

Tags: eclipse, prolog

I'm new user and i need you help with a prolog program.

The sailing club "Thalassa" recently held a contest for young sailors, with boats of two people. The crew of each vessel was a boy and a girl.

1. One member of the crew of the vessel "Ostria" was "Argiris".
2. Magda was neither with "Miltos" nor with "Taki". "Xronis" and "Maro" was not in the "Albatross" and not finished in 24 minutes.
3. "Olga" aboard the "Batis", while the "Aetos" did not finish in 27 minutes.
4. In "Thiella" was or "Miltos" or "Takis" and not aboard the "Basia".
5. "Xara" finished in 16 minutes. "Olga" took more time than "Magda" to finish.
6. "Takis" with her ​​partner finished the race in 21 minutes.

Vessel: "Aetos, "Ostria", "Batis", "Albantros", "Thiella"
Men: "Miltos", "Takis", "Argiris", "Xronis", "Foibos"
wemen: "Maro", "Olga", "Basia", "Magda", "Xara"
times: "16", "19", "21", "24", "27"

i need a program to ask ? solve(X) and gives me a list with the right combination
e.g. X=Aetos, Takis, Maro, 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*edit:* I missed the "eclipse" tag, so perhaps this isn't the answer you're looking for. It works in plain Prolog though, i.e. SWI.

---

So you do have the enumeration of participants, at least we don't need to deduce *that*. Start with it:

- Vessel:  "Aetos, "Ostria", "Batis", "Albatross", "Thiella"
- Men:    "Miltos", "Takis", "Argiris", "Xronis",  "Foibos"
- women:   "Maro",  "Olga",  "Basia",   "Magda",   "Xara"
- times:  "16",     "19",    "21",      "24",      "27"

Rules: **Use the times as values!**:

```
1  Argiris = Ostria,
2  Magda \= Miltos, Magda \= Takis,     
   Xronis \= Albatross, Maro \= Albatross, Xronis \= 24, Maro \= 24, 
     %% does that mean they were together in one boat??
3  Olga = Batis, Aetos \= 27,  
4  ( Thiella = Miltos  ;  Thiella = Takis) ,  Thiella \= Basia,
5  Xara = 16, Olga > Magda,
6  Takis = 21
```

### **Use `select/2` for domain selection:**

```
select([A|B], C):- select(A,C,C2), select(B,C2).
select([],_).
```

We're ready to start coding. The most definite statements go first. It is important to not test any variable until it is defined:

```
sailing(_Vars):-
  Dom = [16,19,21,24,27],     %% the domain
  Takis = 21, 
  select( [Takis, Miltos, Argiris, Xronis, Foibos], Dom), Xronis \= 24, 
  Xara = 16,  
  select( [Xara,  Maro,   Magda,   Olga,   Basia],  Dom), Maro \= 24,
  Magda \= Takis, Magda \= Miltos, Olga > Magda, 
  Olga = Batis, Argiris = Ostria, 
  select( [Batis, Ostria, Aetos, Albatross, Thiella], Dom), Aetos \= 27,
  Thiella \= Basia, 
  (Thiella = Miltos  ;  Thiella = Takis),
  Xronis \= Albatross, Maro \= Albatross.
```

This gives me 57 solutions. So perhaps `Xronis` and `Maro` do need to be put into same boat. Try it.

---

How to report your answer is an additional concern. The above shows the solver.

One way is to tweak the above code as e.g.

```
solve([Takis, Miltos, Argiris, Xronis, Foibos]) :- ... .
```

and call it as `?- solve(Men)`, to see the time assignments for each of `Men`. Another is to alter the code as e.g.

```
pair( A-B, A, B).

solve(Result) :-
  ... ,
  keysort( [Takis-'Takis', Miltos-'Miltos', Argiris-'Argiris',
                          Xronis-'Xronis', Foibos-'Foibos'], TM),
  maplist( pair,TM,Times,Men),
  keysort( [Xara-'Xara',  Maro-'Maro',   Magda-'Magda',   
                         Olga-'Olga',   Basia-'Basia'], TW),
  maplist( pair,TW,Times,Women),
  ... ,
  maplist( pair,TV,Times,Vessels),
  Result = [Vessels,Men,Women,Times],
  maplist( writeln, Result).
```

If you further want to convert the four lists in `Result` into one transposed list of combined data, you can do that too with few more [`maplist/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/4) calls, e.g.

```
maplist( pair,VM,Vessels,Men), maplist( pair,WT,Women,Times),
maplist( quad,Result,VM,WT).

quad( (A,B,C,D), A-B, ... ).
```

Comment: I managed to run this code but i get only TRUE and not any list! (?)

Comment: @GeorgeKostakis Right. Replace `_Vars` with (a list of) variables of interest, e.g. `sailing([Takis, Miltos, Argiris, Xronis, Foibos]):- `. That way, when you call `?- sailing(X)` in SWI it will print back the list of men's times. Or use a list of lists, of men and boats etc.

Comment: I changed the _Vars with boat names... but as return of ?sailing(X) i get a list of numbers and not names.... is it possible to get the names?

Comment: basicly I need the question to be like "?sailing(X)."  and the answer "X=(boat,man,woman,time),(boat,man,woman,time),(boat,man,woman,time),(boat,man,woman,time),(boat,man,woman,time)"

Comment: @GeorgeKostakis to make a list of names out of it there needs to be some more code written. My answer shows the solver; how to present the answer is an additional concern. The simplest is to use [`keysort`](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/agbkb/lehre/pi3/prolog/Manual/builtinlist.html) and [`maplist`](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/agbkb/lehre/pi3/prolog/Manual/applylist.html), an example: `keysort([Takis-'Takis', Miltos-'Miltos',Argiris-'Argiris', Xronis-'Xronis', Foibos-'Foibos'],Z),maplist(snd,Z,Men),writeln(Men)` where `snd` is defined as `snd(_-X,X).`

Comment: if I have something tile [(B1, M1, W1, X1), (B2, M2, W2, X2), (B3, M3, W3, X3)]   and B1, B2, B3 are the Vessels M1, M2, M3 are the men Names etc  how can i check that if Vessel is "Aetos" then Man is "Xronis" ??

Comment: Thank you very mach for your answers. I appreciated.